# Парсинг HTML. Android

Tags: java, android, html

С сервера приходит HTML данные (Заголовок,Описание,URL).
Их нужно спарсить,чтобы корректно отображались в Android приложении. Есть способы? Фреймворки

Comment: JSOUP вам подойдет

Comment: У меня через JSON передается HTML описание, тобишь в String лежит HTML, как его парсить, вместо Jsoup.connect().get?

Comment: JSON с сервера в приложение

Comment: `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);`

Comment: Спасибо,друг :)

Comment: [Только вместо doc.select используй doc.getElementsByTag](https://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/11/android.html)